# Looping through results of a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a query that returns multiple rows.  I can't seem to find a way to store the rows in the $params array.  Is there a way to loop throw and store each row in the $params variable

```
$aResult = $db->exec_sql($sql);  
$params = array(
  // where $aResult[o]'' would be row 1 [1] row 2 etc. //
  'store_id' => $aResult[]['iStoreID'],
  'user_id' => $aResult[]['iUserID'],
  'store_name' => $aResult[]['cStoreName'],
  'store_url' => $aResult[]['cStoreURL'],
  'rid' => $aResult[]['cRID'],
  'affiliate_id' => $aResult[]['iAffiliateID'],
  'team_id' => $aResult[]['iTeamID'],
  'bizOP' => $aResult[]['cDefaultBizOpp'],
  'showBizOPp' => $aResult[]['iShowBizOppDropdown'],
  'boPosting' => $aResult[]['iEnableBOPosting'],
  'brandinglevel' => $aResult[]['iBrandingLevel']
);
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Could you tell us what the exec_sql return?

Comment: `var_dump($aResult);` = ?

Comment: 40=[Array containing 4 elements]
0=[Array containing 14 elements]
iInvoice=""
yAmt="" 
cNameF=""
cNameL=""
cEmail=""
...
That is the dump of what the sql is doing . . . obvoiusly there are more columns and data has been removed but i think it has what is necessary.  Thank you

Comment: To make it easier for people to read you can use the [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17117593/edit) and update it with the dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
$params = array();
foreach($aResult as $row) {
    $params[] = array(
        'store_id' => $row['iStoreID'],
        'user_id' => $row['iUserID'],
        'store_name' => $row['cStoreName'],
        'store_url' => $row['cStoreURL'],
        'rid' => $row['cRID'],
        'affiliate_id' => $row['iAffiliateID'],
        'team_id' => $row['iTeamID'],
        'bizOP' => $row['cDefaultBizOpp'],
        'showBizOPp' => $row['iShowBizOppDropdown'],
        'boPosting' => $row['iEnableBOPosting'],
        'brandinglevel' => $row['iBrandingLevel']
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact structure of the result array i guess you need something like this:

```
<?php

$params  = array();
$mapping = array(
    'store_id' => 'iStoredID',
    'user_id'  => 'iUserID',
// and so on...
);

foreach ($aResult as $row) {
   $tempRow = array();
   foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
       $paramKey           = isset($mapping[$key]) ? $mapping[$key] : $key;
       $tempRow[$paramKey] = $value;
   }
   $params[] = $tempRow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use it like this

```
$aResult = mysql_query($sql);

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     'store_id' = $aResult['iStoreID'];
}
```

At least that is the idea

Comment: Stop using mysql_* functions. This extension is deprecated, and will be soon removed from php. Use mysqli instead or pdo.